# Is it possible to run Ida pro in a docker container?

Tags: ida, windows

I've got a script that runs IDA pro on a file, the problem is that I need to run that script in a windows docker container.

I've got the script working fine, but I can't get the program to run in the container. Just fails without any good error.

I'm wondering if this is even possible or if it requires more than the server core images?

Comment: What IDA version, what Windows version inside the container? Have you tried to use `idat64.exe` (terminal version) with batch-mode argument instead of the regular UI version?